# Without pressing bar button item to load NavigationView in UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

[image]
So I have UISplitview(screen shot attached above). We normally by pressing bar button item in this case is "Monsters" button to open navigation view which is the left-side view and then the right-side view controller will be updated.

My question is, is there any way to load/update the left-side view without pressing the "Monsters" button?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there specific moments where you want to upload/load the left? There are multiple ways of doing so. Also, just making sure, the left view is nothing more than a UItableView right?

Comment: @ophychius I want to call from method and the left view is just a table view. Thanks.